# how can I set up a task to run in background?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, scheduler, task

I am have a web application that is written in c# .net 4.0. It connects to an Oracle database to perform CRUD operations.

What I need to is write a background type tasks that is polling the database at predefined intervals to check to see if it is up. If its down a property in memory is set so that no further requests to the database are made. The task continues to run and alters the property once the database is available again.

I wondering what is the best way to structure such in my application, how I would set up a background task to run etc or any advice on the implementation of such? I don't want this to hog resources on the server so it needs to run in background and not be resource intensive.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a task that should be handled by polling the database periodically. Your application should have proper error handling so that it gracefully fails and reports the failure to the user in the event that a critical component isn't functioning as expected.

Comment: @Servy Thought this was Forms... Deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Service is the obvious answer for background tasks. The basics are pretty easy to do - just create a new project by selecting Windows Service as the project type and go from there.

Inside the Windows Service create an instance of a class and within it create a timer - when the timer fires run your periodic tasks

Comment: He specifically said that this is a web application. He can't create a service within the web application.

Comment: How would the result be communicated in a manor accessible to page requests (i.e. session)?

Comment: Re Web application: afaik you can't have a background task in web application, so some other process running outside the web app is going to be necessary

Comment: Re Communicating Back to Web App: Could be a simple at the Windows Service writing back a file to disk - which the web app checks for?

Comment: @BarneyHDog That's one of those "duct tape" solutions that might work, but is an ugly hack around the fact that *the web application should be able to gracefully handle failure*

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this I would suggest writing a Windows Service, but have it modify a config file setting that your web application checks.  I think having both applications looking at the same config file is the most simple solution in this case.